# How do I just add a custome variable to a Survey Monkey?

Tags: api, surveymonkey, thekofclient

I am handling existing surveys via the API.
As part of this, I need each survey to have a custom variable defined for it.
I would like to use the API to add the custom variable, but the documentation states the FETCH would not do that, and PUT will replace rather than update the survey.
I am handling existing surveys, which I would not like to delete and replace, or am I miss-reading the docs?
Can I just send via PUT the following structure and it will keep everything else in place?

```
{
  id : 112223333, //id of survey
  custom_variables: {
           'custom1':'custom1',
           'custom2':'custom2'
  }
}
```

I do see it resets the title, so, is this method safe? (i.e. wont remove any other data associated to this survey).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. You're going to want to use a `PATCH` HTTP request. That will only make updates, whereas a `PUT` request will replace the survey with the content you provide.

So your request will likely look something like this:

```
PATCH /v3/surveys/<survey_id>
{
    "custom_variables": {
        "custom1_name": "custom1_label",
        "custom2_name": "custom2_label"
    }
}
```

And that should only update your custom variables to the values you set. The [docs](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id) do appear to suggest `custom_variables` won't get updated with a PATCH request but I think it does work.

Comment: works - you should consider returning 204 (I think) instead of 200

Comment: 204 is a `No Content` status code, which should only be returned if there is no body/extra headers attached to the response. We always return the resource so I don't think it applies in this case.

Comment: got it - makes sense